# file extension not valid . when it is

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, file-extension

I can't open a excel file on my home computer. Every other computer I use opens the file apart from this one I use at home .

I get a error message -

> financial.xlsx format is not valid.

This is not corrupt office - I can make new spreadsheets on excel with same extensions.

Comment: 1) The error message seems to indicate that the file is not valid (for whatever program tries to use it). Not that the file extension is not valid.  2) Which program are you trying to open it with at home? Office XP with no extra packs installed?

Answer (score 1):

The **`.xlsx`** format is not compatible with older versions of **`Microsoft Excel`**. The older versions (I believe Versions of Office 2003 and earlier) can read/write the **`.xls`** format, not the **`.xlsx`** format.

To solve this:

1. From the newer version of **`Microsoft Excel`**, use **`Save As`** to save the file in **`.xls`** format.
2. Use the **`Microsoft Compatibility Pack for Word, Excel, and PowerPoint`** ([here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3)) to convert the **`.xlsx`** file.

Also, make sure all Microsoft updates have been applied to Excel on both computers.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your file has a `.xlsx` extension but is a non-Excel file inside. Another potential reason is file or disk corruption.

There is a [blog entry](http://repairmsexcelfile.blogspot.com/) on dealing with Excel file corruption.